# WSASend speed and optimization

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock, iocp

I'm implementing a simplified, static web server inspired by this example:

https://github.com/young2code/IOCP/blob/master/IOCP%20-%20NewThreadPool/Server/Server.cpp

The problem is that WSASend can not exceed 2 Mbit/s on a LAN or on the same machine. WSARecv doesn't have this limitation. The socket is not modified, Nagle is enabled.
Here are the tests I did with Chrome and one active connection on Windows 8.1 64-bit:

- Change to blocking mode (no more IOCP) with a dedicated thread -> no change
- Creation of a dedicated thread pool -> no change
- Various buffer sizes -> no change
- Debug or release -> no change
- Limiting the number of simultaneous posts on the same socket: 0 (new post only after the previous post is completed), 1, 10, 100, 1000: the higher the number is, the higher is the startup speed. After reaching the limit, back to low speed. If no limitation: the use of RAM rises gradually up to 99%.

Is that a congestion problem? incorrect tcp window?
how many packets should be posted simultaneously without waiting for the previous posts notification, for best performance?

---

Found. There is a thread that is awakened by an event each time a new packet is ready to be send from the output FIFO. The bug was that some events were signaled at the same time, therefore they were (viewed as) merged and WSASend was not called as often as necessary.

An advice for the recommended number of simultaneous calls to WSASend before notifications with 16KB packets would be very helpful.

Comment: ' WSASend can not exceed 2 Mbit/s' - how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: I download an Iso or another large file loaded in memory, the browser displays the speed on the client side, and the task manager displays the network use on the server side. The speed is the same for both sides.
However the short bursts (less than 2 or 3 seconds) are correctly handled. The upload rate is 100x higher.

Comment: How many bytes are you passing to `WSASend` in each call?

Comment: The packet size is 16 KB, but same result with 8 KB.